Logout the user when browser tab/window is closed but not on refresh
In one of my Angular projects, I'm facing a problem where the user is gets logged out when the browser is refreshed, but I need to log out only when the browser tab/window is closed. Though, I'm able to log out of the user whenever the browser window/tab is closed, the same logout API call is made whenever I'm refreshing the browser.
Is there any way to differentiate between the browser refresh and browser close? Or is there any way to call the logout API only when the tab/window is closed?
Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Why do you want to log the user out after closing a tab? Seems annoying, especially when you have multiple tabs open at once.

You can try using sessionStorage, it can survive reloads and get cleared when closed

@Reyno i've already fixed the issue of multiple tab scenario, i just want to logout the user when last opened tab is also closed. This is needed in order to track user's active session

you can use sendBeacon for that, but not sure how you'd know it was last tab open: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon

Check Router Events from Angular. There is one called NavigationStart, which has information about destined route. You can use it to verify if target route is the same as current one - then it's reload :)
